# L.circleMarker leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

how to replace circle with icon in L.circleMarker

```
var style_station = {
    radius: 12,
    stroke:false,
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    // color: '#00ABDC',
};
```

$.getJSON("url", function(stationexits){
         exitlayer = L.geoJson(stationexits, {
            onEachFeature: onEachStation,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
               return L.circleMarker(latlng, style_station);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

You will have to return a [L.Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#marker)

Only then will you be able to set your own icon.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to use L.Marker as L.circleMarker have own advantages over L.marker

I did below and its working for me

1)Created a svg pattern like

```
<svg>
  <defs>
   <pattern id="bustop_icon" x="0" y="0" width="18" height="18">
    <image xlink:href="img/images/bus-icon.png" x="3" y="5" width="18" height="20" />
    </pattern>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

2)set className in style

```
    var style_busstops = {
        radius: 12,
        stroke:false,
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        className : 'bus_stops'
    };

L.geoJson(busstops, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, style_busstops);
         }
});
```

3)Add 'fill' css in class bus_stops

```
.bus_stops { 
   fill: url(#bustop_icon);
}
```